# How to remove compatibility in zend framework php version upgrade

Tags: php, zend-framework

I updated my php version from 5.0 to 5.4. After the update of the php version I'm getting ERROR in zend framework. It was running good on php 5.0.

> Strict standards: Declaration of Admin_Model_Admin::CheckExist()
>   should be compatible with Custom_Models_Abstract::CheckExist($tbl,
>   $arr, $operand = '=', $separator = 'AND') in
>   /var/www/html/quickmanhelp/application/modules/admin/models/Admin.php
>   on line 3

Comment: please post the offending code

Comment: this is url of site.  http://dev1.brainpulse.org/quickmanhelp/admin

Comment: Might be because of the ``CheckExist`` in Abstract class has few parameters which are missed in when overriding the ``CheckExist`` in Admin model.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable strict standards checking in php.ini, but that's **not** the right approach. Instead make the signature of your overriding method the same as that in the base class.